# Sorting objects javascript with react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, object

I am doing a project using react and I can not sort the values of several objects.

In fact, here is the structure of my objects:

```
object1:
   subobject1
      hours: "06",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
   subobject2
      hours: "04",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
object2:
   subobject1
      hours: "05",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
   subobject2
      hours: "01",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
```

All recovered objects are in this same form.

I would like to display these objects by sorting on the "hours" property and return an object like this :

```
   object1:
   subobject1
      hours: "04",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
   subobject2
      hours: "06",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
object2:
   subobject1
      hours: "01",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
   subobject2
      hours: "05",
      details:"lorem ipsum",
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks for any help

Edit : sorry, I was wrong about the structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash for such a simple functionality
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy

```
import _ from 'lodash'

objects = [{hours: 1}, {hours: 3}]
sortedObject = _.sortBy(objects, 'hours')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say `data` is an array containing all those objects then

### Ascending

```
var sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => Number(a.hours) - Number(b.hours));
```

### Descending

```
var sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => Number(b.hours) - Number(a.hours));
```

Comment: Hi, problem is it's an object of objects so I didn't see how to use that

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption you are working with an array of objects. If so, this can be simply done with

```
ArrayOfObjects.sort(function(a, b) { return (+a.hours) - (+b.hours) });
```

Or es6

```
ArrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => (+a.hours) - (+b.hours));
```

Comment: Then you can build an array of objects using `Object.keys(ObjectOfObjects)` and then use `.reduce` to recreate your Object of Objects in a dotted manner. .